# Access to user Data throughout the application

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

Iam using firebase authentication, what is the best practice to access to userData in all pages of the application, is that each time you have to subscribe function currentUser to get userID

```
 Future<FirebaseUser> get currentUser async {
   
    return  await _firebaseAuth.currentUser();
  }
```

or I have to store it in a place

Answer (score 2):

You can either call `FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser()` each time, or store its value in a variable or in local storage to pass it around.

Calling `FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser()` each time may result in slightly longer code, but performance-wise it won't be any slower, as Firebase caches the user's authentication state already. Better yet, Firebase also automatically keeps its internal state up to date, so you're guaranteed to get the right state each time you call `FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser()`.

Keeping the user in a local variable may slightly simplify your code, but you'll have to make sure that your variable doesn't get out of sync with the actual authentication state.

I personally typically `FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser()` if I only need the user in one or two places. If I need the user all over the place, I use an `onAuthStateChanged` listener and keep the current state in a member field for easy access.